# Git how to add files using wildcard `git add src/*.vue` in ZSH shell?

Tags: bash, git, zsh

I've just changed to ZSH shell.

Let's say I have some untracked files I want to add in version control

```
git status

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    src/components/Dashboard.vue
    src/components/DashboardInstallations.vue
    src/components/DashboardDevices.vue
```

In Bash I could do,

```
git add src/*.vue
```

This does not work in ZSH; the files are not added. Any ideas to avoid adding these manually one at a time?!

Comment: `src/*.vue`? Don't you want `src/*/*.vue`? Do you get a "no matches found" message? Why not `src/components/*.vue`?

Comment: No there is not error message with `git add src/*.vue`. But git add `src/*/*.vue` works! I guess I was expected the pattern matching to match the directory "`/`" as well as file names. Thanks. And add an answer so I can close.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't expect `src/*.vue` to automatically recurse in bash either; in bash, one needs `shopt -s globstar` to enable `src/**/*.vue` (though admittedly, some distros ship with dotfiles that turn that on by default); the `**` syntax is always required.

Comment: I’m on MacOS. It’s the behaviour I’ve always observed. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` matches entries within current directory - it's not recursive, only entried in the directory are matched. You may use `*/` to match only directories, which makes `path/*/*.vue` match files within any subdirectories. There is `**` in bash and zsh that matches paths recursively, so you can also `path/**/*.vue` to match `vue` files recursively (ie. match `path/a/b/c/d/f.vue` and `path/b/a.vue`). For further information research `glob(7)` and how filename expansion works in both shells.